# Automate the "Reset this PC" process

Tags: windows-10, automation

On one of my Windows 10 PCs, I perform the "[Reset this PC](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10/how-to-perform-a-clean-install-using-reset-this-pc/6f6335fc-8d15-4598-af16-033d1d8c16bf)" process every week, removing everything from the storage device (files, applications, etc). Every time I do so, I need to click through various options like keyboard layout, location, etc.

I would like to automate this process as much as possible. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Automating the computer setup process requires answer files typically used in imaging. I don't know how these answer files can be integrated into the "Reset This PC" process, but I would imagine that if you want to go back to a fresh install, creating an image that is fully customized in this regard would accomplish the same thing. So, have you looked into basic imaging?

Comment: @music2myear - They can't be.  The proper course of action would be to use DISM to apply a .wim onto a partition.

Comment: Have you considered deep freeze ?

Comment: To my surprise, my question got 5 downvotes in less than a day! I wouldn't expect that such a clear question, which is well researched (if it wasn't it would have been answered already) would be treated that way.

Thank you @music2myear for the work around. I will consider doing it that way.

Comment: There are several ways this question can be improved: There is no indication of research. You say you've researched, but the question lacks any reference to or proof of that research. The question shows that a process is being performed but does not give the "why". If you explain the "why" we may be able to provide a much better solution that you may not have considered yet. Also, related to that second point, you allude to a process that has me (and I assume many others) scratching our heads. What circumstances lead you to need to reset a computer every week. What about virtualizing?

Comment: I understand but I can't prove my research when results=0. I didn't say why I need this, because of this: We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. Clear-cut question, laser-focused to the problem at hand. Pardon me, I'm quite new here and don't know all the tricks yet. I just try to follow the platform's suggestions. I didn't think about the alternative you suggested. But I thought that was the point of this platform. Maybe I should have spent more days searching on my own. Anyway, thank you all for your contributions and your guidance. I'll post the answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't find any way to script the "Reset this PC" process, I explored the workaround suggested by @music2myear, which yields almost the same results.

## Windows installation with unattend.xml setup file

There is a [Microsoft Documented process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oem-windows-deployment-and-imaging-walkthrough), to deploy Windows using an answer file named **unattend.xml**. This file guides the installation process and provides all the information needed by the installer (like product key, language, etc).

Following the above process is not an easy task to do, but there is a more easy way to accomplish the same result. The site [www.windowsafg.com](http://www.windowsafg.com) provides an easy way to create the autounattend.xml file. For my need I used the [x64 UEFI answer file generator](http://www.windowsafg.com/win10x86_x64_uefi.html) and provided the [Microsoft Generic Keys](https://winaero.com/blog/generic-key-to-install-windows-10-rtm/) to install Windows (before anyone rushes to report this post for alleged providing Windows Keys, the above keys are provided by [Microsoft themselves](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/generic-key-windows-10/57a8ea86-6215-43e9-9958-90aea4888149) and have a special use case).

### Procedure

1. Use the above tool to provide all the information needed
2. Download the file autounattend.xml using the link at the bottom of that page
3. Empty/Format a USB Flash Drive and place the autounattend.xml file in the flash drive. Make sure it's the only file on the drive.
4. Plug the flash drive to the computer that you need to setup
5. Insert the Windows 10 DVD Media to the DVD drive and start the installation

### Troubleshooting

If during the installation you get the following error:

> Windows could not create a partition on disk 0. The error occured while applying the unattend answer file’s  setting. Error code: 0x80042565

then check [this article for the solution](http://www.jc-tech.info/2016/06/02/deployment-error-windows-could-not-create-a-partition/).

### Notes

["unattend.xml" and "autounattend.xml"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a58f4334-3f34-4874-863a-34b0bd1282b8/quotunattendxmlquot-and-quotautounattendxmlquot)